# Symfony2 - form collection delete_empty fails

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have an embedded form collection field. Parent is the inverse side, child (embedded) is the owning side. I want to dynamically allow for adding/removing children. Adding works, removing also (with the help of orphanRemoval=true). When I leave the child form empty I get:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO child
(content, completed, parent_id, created_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'
with params [null, 0, 30,  8]: Column 'content' cannot be null
```

The content field is the only one thats rendered. The field shouldn't be persisted at all since 'delete_empty' and 'allow_delete' are both set in the field type.
Any ideas why this happens?

EDIT:

I removed all the metadata from the entity to make sure it is really empty. Doctrine tries to insert (null,null,null,null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this issue. I was adding the empty child in the createForm method. The logic went as follows:

#### Edit action:

```
$parent = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:parent')->find($id);
$editForm->createEditForm($parent)
```

#### Create edit form method:

```
public function createEditForm(Parent $parent){
    $child = new Child();
    $parent->setChild($child);
    $form = $this->createForm(...)
```

#### Fix:

The child needed to be added in the edit action, before creating the form (so the entity passed to form creation already had the empty entity).

Comment: Can you clarify what the solution is? I don't understand what difference it would make if you instantiate the child in the method or before.

Comment: Frankly @RyanB – I don't know. I reported it already as a bug on Symfony2 github issue tracker.